# List of Selenium IDE commands compatible with export to Java/WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, formatter

I have created a bunch of tests in Selenium IDE which I plan to export to Java. Trying the export for the first time today, I expected to get Java code which would compile after minor polishing, but I was unpleasantly surprised by the number of unsupported commands which would not be exported:

```
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [setTimeout | ${page_timeout} | ]]
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [rollup | select_tile | tile='${nonreg_asset}']]
```

Googling for similar issues brought even more Selenium IDE commands which are not supported, like `waitForPopUp`, `mouseOver` etc. I wonder if there is a list of such commands one should avoid in order to facilitate the export. I bet `store` command would be in that list; although the command itself is converted somehow, any other command trying to use the stored values seems to be offending.

Comment: As it turns out, the `store` command is not unsupported but rather working differently in the exported code. In Selenium IDE, stored values persist across test cases, while in exported code they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is not a list of what exactly you are looking for, at least not that I know. But, sure there is a list of api available in different packages that might help you to understand. So far I know, it is not very feasible to record and export the selenium tests for long run. Look [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html) for the list of all available classes. Answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809970/how-to-select-proper-action-for-web-target-in-selenium-ide/25811131#25811131)

Comment: I don't quite understand how the list of available classes relates to the list of commands eligible for code generation. For example, `WebDriver.Timeouts` class does exist, yet setTimeout command is unsupported, even with literal timeout values like 1234.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Unfortunately there isn't a list of IDE command that are compatible with webdriver. The list I prvided is for slenium web driver and `Java` binding. You can look at those class and determine what can be converted what can't be